# While in chrome console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, console

Running a simple string:

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName("case".toLowerCase())[0].textContent.toLowerCase() !== "boredom") {
 $("#button").click()
}
```

After the successful click page is refreshed.

And this works fine, however I need to make this infinite until boredom reached.

Tried with loop:

```
 while(document.getElementsByClassName("word".toLowerCase())[0].textContent.toLowerCase() !== "blast") {
 $("#button-0").click()
}
```

but chrome goes into infinite loop without clicking/refreshing the page. Only killing the process helps.

Comment: Cause the first element [0] has never glawk?

Comment: Yes, but workflow is following: If not boredom = click the button. After the click page refreshed and new element appears. And it works with IF, however with the while page is not refreshing, hence boredom will be never reached.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *iterate* , or the loop is useless:

```
var words=document.getElementsByClassName("word");
for(var i=0; i<words.length;i++){
 if(words[i].textContent.toLowerCase() === "blast") {
   $("#button-0").click();
   break;
 }
}
```

Or if you like obfuscated code:

```
!Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("word")).some(el=>el.textConent.toLowerCase()==="blast")|| $(" #button-0").click();
```

PS:

You can add script as a bookmark if you put *javascript:* before it. Have a look at *bookmarklets*...

Comment: Just tried and looks same as IF, cause needs to be ran manually after each refresh

Comment: @fleshgakker you may write a chrome addon :/

Comment: @fleshgakkerexecute that IF function in ready event of document

Comment: In console also you can do that

Comment: @koushik chatterjee *cause needs to be run manually after refresh* and you think a listener will survive a refresh ? :/

Comment: @Jonasw after refresh, whatever you are running manually, instead add a listener and out it inside, and run that manualy

Comment: @Jonasw Exactly :)

Comment: @koushik Did you mean something like: function validate(){
if(document.getElementsByClassName("word".toLowerCase())[0].textContent.toLowerCase() !== "blast") {
 $("#button").click()
}
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  // we call the function
  validate();
});

Comment: @fleshgakker thats unneccessary. If you start it manually you wont need it. And to automate ut, you need much more code.